# Codeception RuntimeException Call to undefined method FunctionalTester::amOnPage

Tags: php, symfony, unit-testing, codeception

I have set up a functional test following the tutorials at:

- http://codeception.com/docs/04-FunctionalTests
- http://codeception.com/docs/modules/Symfony
- http://codeception.com/09-04-2015/using-codeception-for-symfony-projects.html

The main difference is that I've set up Codeception the traditional way because I don't want to mix test code with project code.

This is my functional test (I know it's not actually testing anything):

```
<?php

class MyFirstCest {
  public function _before(FunctionalTester $I) {
  }

  public function _after(FunctionalTester $I) {
  }

  // tests
  public function tryToTest(FunctionalTester $I) {
    $I->amOnPage('/app/login/');
  }
}
```

When I run the functional test I get:

> `[RuntimeException] Call to undefined method FunctionalTester::amOnPage`

When I re`build` Codeception, I get:

> `Building Actor classes for suites: acceptance, functional, unit
>    -> AcceptanceTesterActions.php generated successfully. 0 methods added
>   \AcceptanceTester includes modules: PhpBrowser, \Helper\Acceptance
>    -> FunctionalTesterActions.php generated successfully. 0 methods added
>   \FunctionalTester includes modules:
>    -> UnitTesterActions.php generated successfully. 0 methods added
>   \UnitTester includes modules: Asserts, \Helper\Unit`

The critical part seems to be `\FunctionalTester includes modules:` which is empty.

My `functional.suite.yml` file looks like this:

```
actor: FunctionalTester
modules:
    - Symfony:
        app_path: 'app'
        environment: 'local_test'
class_name: FunctionalTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Symfony2:
            app_path: 'path/to/app'
            var_path: 'path/to/app'
        - Doctrine2:
            depends: Symfony2
        - \Helper\Functional
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: dev.hmr-app
        - \AcmeBundle\Helper\Functional
```

where the Symfony app lives in `path/to/app`. I know there's a lot of junk in there, but that's because I've been experimenting, trying to get it to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think that your problem is that you have

```
modules:
    - Symfony:
        app_path: 'app'
        environment: 'local_test'
```

in the config.

That section is completely misplaced and it probably is causing you issues.
Please remove it and rename Symfony2 with Symfony in enabled section.

Also make sure that you are using the latest version of Codeception.

Comment: Codeception is already the latest (2.3.6 currently). I removed all references to Symfony, and now it runs without errors although I still have no output. I will ask a separate question if I can't get the output working. I'm not sure at the moment how necessary it is to have Symfony configured in the `functional.suite.yml` file.